# HTML Footer floating slightly above bottom of page at certain resolutions

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my website ready for a collage interview, and it's almost finished, but I cannot work out why my footer is floating above the bottom of my page if the size of the windows is above a certain size.

I'll include the HTML and CSS used here:

```css
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

body{
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
}

.clr{
    clear: both;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar .container{
    margin: 0;
}

.button{
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    color: white;    
}

.button:hover{
    background-color: green;
}

#myHeader{
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

#myHeader .container{
    width: 90%;
}

#navbar{
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    color: white;
    
}

#navbar ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar li{
    display: inline;
}

#navbar a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px;

}

#showcase{
    background-image: url("../Images/showcase.jpg");
    background-position: center right;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: white;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#showcase h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#main{
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    padding:0 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    color: white;
    padding:0 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mainFooter{
    background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

@media(max-width: 600px){

    #main{
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    
    #sidebar{
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Finn Llewellyn</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="myHeader">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Finn Llewellyn</h1>
            </div>
        </header>

        <nav id="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="button" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a class="button" href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a class="button" href="#">Cool Things</a></li>
                    <li>Note: These don't do anyting yet lol</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <section id="showcase">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Computers are cool lol</h1>
                <h2>That's why this site is awful on mobile</h2>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="container">
            <section id="main">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
                <p>
                    My name is Finn Llewellyn. I'm a tech enthusiast that has been following PC and mobile hardware for a while. I know far too much about computers, how they work, and 
                    which spec components will best suit a specific use case. I also like to think I'm alright at diagnosing and solving technical issues. Staying
                    true to my other geeky attributes, I'm fluent in python, which is quite useful I suppose, although it would potentially be more useful to learn
                    a real, spoken language, like Spanish. Hopefully i can scrape a good GCSE in it, along with my Maths, English, Double Science, Computer Science,
                    Resistant Materials and History GCSEs. Especially Maths, Scince and Computer Scinece, as I wish to continue these subjects at A-Level, or maybe a 
                    B-Tech in softwar/app development.
                </p>
            </section>
            <aside id="sidebar">
                <h1>Cool Things</h1>
                <ol>
                    <li>Star Wars</li>
                    <li>Half-Life series</li>
                    <li>DOOM</li>
                    <li>Radiohead</li>
                    <li>Blur</li>
                    <li>R.E.M</li>
                    <li>YouTube</li>
                    <li>AMD Ryzen CPUs</li>
                    <li>Other geeky stuff</li>
                </ol>
            </aside>
        </div>

        <div id="mainFooter">
            <p>This footer is just here to look nice</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've already tried adding `position: absolute;`, `width: 100%;` and `bottom: 0;` to the footer class, but it would cover content if it reached that far down the page.

I would appreciate absolutely any help.

Comment: Just tested your code and there isn't any space on my screen, my guess is that your monitor is bigger than mine, one solution I can think of is putting all your page content inside a container, then setting `min-height: calc(100vh - the height of the footer)` so it uses the remaining space

Comment: Yep, best way to get this to fill fully is to calculate your content section of your page based off of the page height.  Right now the reason it only appears on larger monitors is because your page just happens to nearly fill a 1080p screen, so anything smaller than that would look normal.  The current padding is coming from your margin-top on the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this? I just added an additional container and set a minimum height to it so it uses the available space in the viewport and pushes the footer to the bottom.

To further explain, you have 3 main sections on your page:

- Navar or Header
- Content
- Footer

The idea is to make the content as tall as your screen so the footer is not positioned above the bottom edge of the screen. So you can just create a single container where all of your content's sections will be, and adding some CSS to make it use all that available height.

What I did then was creating the `main-container` div, and then adding a single CSS rule:

`.main-container: {min-height: calc(100vh - 221px)}`

I use the `calc()` function so I can have a bit more control on the final size, in this case, 221px is the sum of your footer's total height + the navbar's total height (you can confirm this just by inspecting each element), so now the `.main-containr` will have a minimum height of your total screen minus the space used by the footer and navbar, that way, if you have little content on the screen, the footer will still be at the bottom edge because the main container is using that space.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*
  Target the element that holds all your content, and set a minimum height so it uses the full viewport height (100vh)
  
*/

.main-content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 221px)
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 0;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar .container {
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#myHeader {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

#myHeader .container {
  width: 90%;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
}

#navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

#navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url("../Images/showcase.jpg");
  background-position: center right;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: white;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#main {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mainFooter {
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  #main {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  #sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="myHeader">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Finn Llewellyn</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="button" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="#">Cool Things</a></li>
        <li>Note: These don't do anyting yet lol</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <!-- Group all of your content inside a single container, not including the navbar and the footer -->
  <div class="main-content">
    <section id="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Computers are cool lol</h1>
        <h2>That's why this site is awful on mobile</h2>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="container">
      <section id="main">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <p>
          My name is Finn Llewellyn. I'm a tech enthusiast that has been following PC and mobile hardware for a while. I know far too much about computers, how they work, and which spec components will best suit a specific use case. I also like to think I'm alright
          at diagnosing and solving technical issues. Staying true to my other geeky attributes, I'm fluent in python, which is quite useful I suppose, although it would potentially be more useful to learn a real, spoken language, like Spanish. Hopefully
          i can scrape a good GCSE in it, along with my Maths, English, Double Science, Computer Science, Resistant Materials and History GCSEs. Especially Maths, Scince and Computer Scinece, as I wish to continue these subjects at A-Level, or maybe a
          B-Tech in softwar/app development.
        </p>
      </section>
      <aside id="sidebar">
        <h1>Cool Things</h1>
        <ol>
          <li>Star Wars</li>
          <li>Half-Life series</li>
          <li>DOOM</li>
          <li>Radiohead</li>
          <li>Blur</li>
          <li>R.E.M</li>
          <li>YouTube</li>
          <li>AMD Ryzen CPUs</li>
          <li>Other geeky stuff</li>
        </ol>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="mainFooter">
    <p>This footer is just here to look nice</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, works perfectly now. Is it possible for you to explicitly state all the changes you made, just so I have a full understanding.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some comments on the code, but as a headsup, I put all the content except for the `navbar` and the `footer` inside a container with a class of `main-content`... Then just added a CSS Rule `.main-content: min-height: calc(100vh-221px)}`, where 221px is the sum of the heights of the navbar and footer

Comment: You are a legend mate. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

What about applying `position: relative` and `bottom: 0` to your `#mainFooter` element?

Using `relative` instead of `absolute` positioning should prevent the footer from covering other content.

```
#mainFooter{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    /* other styling properties like color etc... */
}
```

Comment: Nothing appears to have happened after entering those properties, the gap hasn't changed size or anything, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the space below the footer is because the content no longer takes up all the available space, and there is no longer any scrollable content. You could just increase the amount of content, white space etc. so that the content takes up at least the viewport height on larger screens.